# HBase oldWALs, pv2-(sequence number).log are not cleaned up

Tags: hdfs, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I'm wondering if someone has any idea about the following problem.

The oldWALs directory on hdfs only seems to be cleaned partially, the (quite small) pv2-(sequence number).log files just keep increasing (every hour or so a file is added)

What master process is supposed to clean these specific files? And what is the purpose of those pv2 log files? Because I also see a couple with 0bytes.

Settings:
hbase.master.logcleaner.ttl=60000
In zookeeper under the hbase znode peers -> empty
Replication is false

Answer (score 0):

Files prefixed with `pv2-` are WAL files of [Procedure Framework (Pv2)](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#pv2).
If your cluster have many such files, this can indicate that some procedure was stuck and hold related WAL files(which contains 'state' of procedure).
You can list current procedures using HBase shell (`list_procedures` command) or see 'Procedures & Locks' page in the Master user interface.

Also, HBase PV2 has property `hbase.procedure.store.wal.warn.threshold`(default value 10, depends on HBase version) which configure count of PV2 wals after which HBase will log warnings with following text:
`procedure WALs count={count_of_logs} above the warning threshold {threshold_value}. check running procedures to see if something is stuck`.